# How to combine a tree ADT which will either be a BST or an RBT depending on the an enumerated type which gets passed to tree_new()?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree, abstract-data-type

Ive written code for both RBTs and BSTs, however i am unsure how to combine them together into one data structure?

How would I go about combining these into one data structure?

```
  struct rbtnode{                                                                 
     char *key;                                                                  
     colour_t colour;                                                            
     rbt right;                                                                  
     rbt left;                                                                   
  };    
  struct bstnode{                                                                 
     char *key;                                                                  
     tree left;                                                                  
     tree right;                                                                 
                                                                            
 };
```

How would I go about creating a function which creates a new tree depending on the enumerated type that is passed to the function?

Comment: One option: Have a wrapper struct with an `enum` field for the type and a `union` field for a node pointer of each type.

Comment: Maybe create a so-called tagged union data structure. `struct UDP_IP_Parameters { 
        uint tree_type; // 1 for bst, and 2 for rbt
        union tree {
            struct rbtnode;
            struct bstnode;
        };
};`

Comment: Something like this? 
typedef enum tree_e {BST, RBT} tree_t;  
union bst_or_rbt_node{                           
    struct bstnode bst_node;                     
    struct rbtnode rbt_node;                     
};

Comment: Note that RB does not actually need any extra data members on reasonable hardware. The color can be hidden in the low bits of one of the pointers (same can be done for an AVL tree although that needs at least two bits per node rather than just one like RB). So, using the same node type for both implementations it is then just a matter of storing your enum value in the containing tree and then selecting an implementation function when tree_insert or tree_erase is called.